# Is there any way to skip the "Install" step in Azure pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines, newman, automation-testing

So I am trying to automate the API testing through Azure pipelines and I have to install "newman" every time which takes a lot of time. So is there any way that I do not have to install newman while running the pipeline? Or any other approach that can be used?

Comment: Configure a self-hosted agent and install whatever software you need on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install "newman" on your Self-hosted agent and specify Self-hosted agent to run the "newman" job.

"newman" is not an included software for Microsoft-hosted agents. Check this link: [[Microsoft-hosted agents for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[image]

Also, you could raise a feedback ticket to install "newman" as default software for Microsoft-hosted agents: [[Suggest a feature - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. Apart from this I was also trying to run the Newman on docker container inside the pipeline but the one you suggested might be easier

Comment: Hi, so glad that my suggestion could help you with your issue. Would you mark this as an answer?